# Create Frequency Map Using Map - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, frequency

Trying to solve this [Codwars Kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/find-duplicates/train/javascript).

> Given an array, find the duplicates in that array, and return a new array of those duplicates. The elements of the returned array should appear in the order when they first appeared as duplicates.

Examples:

```
[1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 3, '5']  ==>  [4, 3, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                ==>  []
```

I have:

```js
function duplicates(arr) {

  arr.sort((value, index) => value - index);
  let duplicates = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === arr[i + 1]) {
      duplicates.unshift(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  //filter out duplicates within "duplicates"
  duplicates = duplicates.filter((value, index) =>
     duplicates.indexOf(value) == index);
  return duplicates;
}

console.log(duplicates([1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, '5']));
```

This is passing all tests except for one:

> Expected: '[1, 4]', instead got: '[4, 1]'

And I'm not sure why - unfortunately it does not *display* the test case.

It was suggested that another way to create a frequency map, however, is with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). How would I do this?

I tried:

```js
function duplicates(arr) {

  let map = new Map([arr]);
  return map;

}

console.log(duplicates([1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, '5']));
```

and this doesn't create a frequency map.

What other suggestions would you have?

**NOTE** - "5" and 5 should not count as the same value.

**EDIT** - Initially, tried to create a frequencyMap like this:

```
function duplicates(arr) {
  let map = {};
  arr.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (!map[value]) {
      map[value] = 0;
    }
    map[value] += 1;
  })
  return map;
}

console.log(duplicates([1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, '5']));
```

But in this case, "5" and 5 are considered to be the same value. I don't know how else to check for duplicates - sorting disrupts the order in which the duplicates appear; and creating a frequencyMap count numbers and strings as the same thing.

Comment: The instructions say: `The elements of the returned array should appear in the order when they first appeared as duplicates.` But the first thing you do is throw that information away by sorting the array.

Comment: I remember now why I sorted - I had tried to create a frequencyMap, but that counted 5 and "5" as the same thing, which is also against the rules.

Comment: Use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an object to keep count. It distinguishes types for keys.

Comment: @MarkMeyer right, that's what I'm not understanding - how can I use `Map` to keep count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea that should work:

Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (map keys distinguish type so `5` is a different key than `"5"`)

Use filter to go through the items in your array. As you go through keep count of how many times you've seen an item in your Map. Return `true` from the filter only when the count (before you've increased it) is `1`. That's the second time you've seen that item.

The filter should return your answer:

```js
function duplicates(arr) {
   let counts = new Map()
   return arr.filter(n => {
        let count = counts.get(n)
        counts.set(n, count ? count+1 : 1)
        return count === 1     
   })
}

console.log(duplicates([1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, '5']));
```

Comment: That is say set key `n` in the map. The new value will be count + 1 if `count` is "truthy" (defined, non-zero, etc). Otherwise set it to 1 .

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most efficient solution, but it solves the challenge. Note, I'm using js `object` to mimic a Map

```js
 function duplicates(arr) {
  // TODO: return the array of duplicates from arr
  const map = {};
  const dup = {};

  for (const val of arr) {
    let key = val;
    if (typeof val === 'string') {
      key = `${val}_str`;
    }

    if (map[key]) {
      dup[val] = true;
    } else {
      map[key] = true;
    }
  }
  return Object.keys(dup)
  .map( d => (!Number.isInteger(parseInt(d))) ? d : Number(d));
}

console.log(duplicates([1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, '5']));
```